# How do you put a server that connects to a mongoDB atlas database with node.js on your personal website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb-atlas

I have been recently been working on a incremental game called Gti clicker clickersandbeyond.com/Gti-Clicker/ and I have been saving the score to localstorage, and it works just fine but I want to be able to connect to a mongoDB atlas database with node to save the score.

I have tried watching lots of youtube videos but none of them have helped me.

I am **sort** of good at node.js but I don't know how to connect my nodejs and mongoDB atlas server to my github page (I have a custom domain clickersandbeyond.com/Gti-Clicker/) I just need some guidance on how to connect to mongoDB atlas and do the node.js to connect to my website.

Answer (score 0):

To connect MongoDB with NodeJs, you need to use the MongoDB driver. You can use the official [MongoDB NodeJs driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb). You can start from https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb#quick-start . You just need the connection URL from MongoDB Atlas and this MongoDB driver to connect you NodeJs app to MongoDB.

Comment: Okay yes I can now connect but I want to put it on my website and save variables to the DB

Comment: @Hank could you please elaborate more.

Comment: So what I want to do is put my node.js to my website. Is there a way you can make the backend search for my website instead of locolhost and work on everyones compupter?